# How to get full price for money gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, currency

i am using the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) and i wanted to know **how i can get prices like 23.45, 10.00, 0.32 to show in one field as dollar.cents?** I want my cents field to become just Price (money or dollars & cents).

Here is my code:

**My model with money gem composed_of:**

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :date, :cents, :currency

    belongs_to :user

    validates :name,       :presence => true,
                           :length   => { :maximum => 50 }

    validates :currency,   :presence => true
    validates :cents,      :presence => true
    validates :date,       :presence => true

    default_scope :order => 'prices.created_at DESC'

    composed_of :price,
        :class_name => "Money",
        :mapping => [%w(cents cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
        :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) },
        :converter => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money : raise(ArgumentError, "Can't convert #{value.class} to Money") }
end
```

**The form (i cut out parts for brevity):**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cents %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :cents %>
  </div>
  <><div class="field">
    <%= f.label :currency %><br />
    <%= f.select(:currency,major_currencies(Money::Currency::TABLE), 
    {:include_blank => 'Select a Currency'}) %>
  </div>
```

**My migration or Price Table:**

```
class CreatePrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :prices do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :name
      t.date :date
      t.integer :cents, :default => 0
      t.string :currency
```

It seems like i am missing a column or something. It is even suppose to be cents alone? Not sure so i need your help.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798651/rails-money-gem-converts-all-amounts-to-zero/4800159

Comment: Just by looking at it: you have cents in DB and currency in the view (whichever it is), so 23.45 in currency == 2345 cents.

Comment: @apneadiving I actually followed the accepted answer you gave to get me started, created everything like that and still get the problem above.

Comment: @santuxus I was thinking the same thing but I'm not sure how to configure it so i get the full amount instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i was able to figure it out, thanks everyone!

Here is my new code:

Database now is :price instead of :cents -

```
create_table :prices do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.string :name
  t.date :date
  t.integer :price, :default => 0
  t.string :currency
```

form area:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
```

new composed_of:

```
composed_of :price,
    :class_name  => "Money",
    :mapping     => [%w(price cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
    :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) },
    :converter   => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money : raise(ArgumentError, "Can't conver #{value.class} to Money") }
```

I just had to make it so the **composed_of** matches the **mapping, database column and form** and for some strange reason it starting working entirely. Thanks everyone for the help, i learned a great deal about ruby and the rails.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the exact same problem, and if you don't want to change your DB like you did in your chosen answer, simply take a look at the source code of the gem to see if there is anything that you can use:

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/lib/money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension.rb

In this module, you will notice two things:

1. A method named humanize_money
2. Within that method, a call to the method format on a money object

So, simply call **@my_money_object.format**, and....bam, you have your money object format to a string WITH the dollars, and the cents amount with a precision of 2.

Example:

```
@my_money_object = 20.to_money
@my_money_object.format
```

=> "$20.00"

This is really the correct solution. You specifically said that you "just want the method on getting a full price like $ 45.23." Now if you want to put this formatted string in your DB like that, it is up to you, but I would consider just calling the format method on the money object where needed. I needed to get the formatted price in a controller and obviously didn't have access to the humanize_money method unless I am in a view (without trying to hack out an additional method to do this), so I checked out the source code and found this.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

In your DB table you hold cents as integers:

```
 t.integer :cents, :default => 0
```

Try changing that to:

```
 t.decimal :cents, :default => 0
```

Comment: Now this works to a degree, i can put 23.45 but if i put 23.50 it comes out 23.5 instead.

Comment: 23.50 is exactly the same as 23.5 - if you want the 0 at the end, I think you have to format it in ruby

Comment: You right, but so people don't get confused, it makes more sense ( heh cents) for $ 23.50.

Comment: the data is coming from the DB as a number - you need to convert it as a string to pad id with zeroes. To your particular case, it would make more sense if it was with a 0 in the end - but there is no way to know how many zeroes makes sense to put by default

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the gem and tested a few options. Following the examples from https://github.com/RubyMoney/money you can do:

```
money = Money.new(1000, "USD")
money.cents     #=> 1000
money.dollars   #=> 10.0
```

So in my opinion you should have something like this method in your model Price:

```
def value
  cents / 100.0
end
```

And use it in the views (or wherever you need value in currency, not cents). When adding a price you are doing it in cents, thus to have a price 12.34 you should set it to 1234 cents. If you want to add price like 12.34, I guess you should parse it in controller (on create/update action) or in the model with filter before_save or something like that. Just multiply it by 100 to save as cents in DB.

EDIT:
helper method to add zeros to view.

```
def with_zeros(price)
  array = price.to_s.split('.')
  array[1] = array[1].ljust(2,'0')
  array.join('.')
end
```

Comment: I actually dont want to do it in cents, i was just following the tutorials and questions on this website. I just want the method on getting a full price like $ 45.23 in one field.

Comment: In this case, I think that Tudor Constantin gave a solution that you are looking for... You can add a helper method that adds zeros that you want in the view. (I added the code above - it returns string with to digits after comma)