# Rails and dates, are they stored in UTC by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way for me to handle dates and timezones in rails?

Scenerio:   I have customers who purchase products on a website from all over the world, and when they log in they will be able to choose which timezone they are from.

So I believe I should be storing everything in the database at UTC, and then on the front-end I should be converting the dates to the users set timezone preference.

Are their any gotchas with Ruby and Rails and datetimes etc?

I'm new to rails, so I am looking for guidance on how to handle this properly.

Comment: I'd do exactly as you describe: record everything as UTC. What's your question here though?

Comment: does active record store things in UTC by default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fortunately Rails will pretty much handle things for you.  As others pointed out, dates are stored by AR in UTC format.  If you have a `time_zone` field for your users table you can do something like this:

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = "Mountain Time (US & Canada)" # Default time zone
```

-

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :set_time_zone, :if => :logged_in?

protected
def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if current_user.time_zone
end
```

All the datetimes should be shown in the proper time zone in your views.

I have had one production app that didn't like using the default time zone, but I can't remember which version of Rails/Ruby it was running.

Comment: thanks, hopefully I have understood everything as it seems straight forward!  now for money/currency issues :)

Comment: @Blankman: for money/currencies issue, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798651/rails-money-gem-converts-all-amounts-to-zero/4800159#4800159

Answer (score 2):

Ok so take a look at your `config/application.rb` file.

You should find commented lines:

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

So default is `UTC` but you can set whatever ou need there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. In app, whenever you display date or time for user, everything you need is just adding timezone offset (for example: `date + 1.hour` for GMT+1). Remember that you need to take care of daylight saving, too. For efficency, consider adding 2 columns in your user table: timezone and time_offset. Then you would on each case do something like

```
= @order.created_at + session[:user].time_offset
```

Instead of always checking offset for each timezone set in profile.

Comment: I'm confused, you said to have 2 columns but your code doesn't make reference to the timezone column?

Comment: It's meant to not have. You use timezone when user edits his/her profile - it's "human friendly" name. When user updates it - you compare it with a table of timezones and offsets, and set time_offset to not get that offset again.

Comment: Okay, I see that Wizard of Ogz proposed better solution, I didn't knew that Rails have something like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
rake time:zones:all
```

to be really useful. It shows a list of offsets and then zone name strings under that. eg:

```
* UTC +12:00 * 
Auckland 
Fiji
Kamchatka
Magadan
Marshall Is.
Solomon Is.
Wellington
```

I needed below in application.rb (not intuitive given default time zone string of "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"):

```
config.time_zone = 'Wellington'
```